# How do I add an image in a bootstrap card?

Tags: html, django

I am trying to attach an image in a specific area in a card, but I don't know how to. I am sorry if it's a very silly question, I am a total beginner in terms of html. So can anyone please show me how to do it? It would have been really useful.

I am using Django. For example, If I want to add an image in that specific blue outlined area, what should I do?
[image]

My code

```
{% for fixture in fixtures %}
  <div class="card bg-light">
    <div class="card-header" style="color:red;" >
      Featured
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title" style="color:black;">{{ fixture.home_team }} vs {{ fixture.away_team }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text" style="color:black;">{{ fixture.description }}</p>
    <form style="color:black;">
      <h5><label for="watching">Watching?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="watching" name="watching" value="watching">
      </h5>
    </form>
  </div>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: since this is somewhat related to CSS why don't you post your stylesheet?

Comment: I don't really have a separate stylesheet for this

Comment: But if I can solve it by doing it, please suggest how

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try

```
<div class="card bg-light">
    <div class="card-header" style="color:red;" >
      Featured
    </div>

    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md-6">
            <h5 class="card-title" style="color:black;">{{ fixture.home_team }} vs {{ fixture.away_team }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text" style="color:black;">{{ fixture.description }}</p>
          <form style="color:black;">
            <h5><label for="watching">Watching?</label>
              <input type="checkbox" id="watching" name="watching" value="watching">
            </h5>
          </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col col-md-6">
          <img src="https://lab.oliveiraweb.com.br/images-for-samples/owl.jpg" class="img-fluid">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```